# How to remove previous function outputs when another button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently working on a project where I create menu for thanksgiving. I want to know how I can get rid of the previous functions from my code so it doesn't stack on top of my other codes. I'm a newbie to python so I'm not sure what to do.

Here when I clicked on the first button it seems to work fine.

[image: before]

But when I clicked on another button it just stacks on top of each other, how do I get rid of that?

[image: after]

Here's my codes:*

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
thanksgiving = Tk()
thanksgiving.geometry("1200x700")
thanksgiving.title("THaNksGivInG")
title = Label(thanksgiving, font = ("impact", 20 ), text = "A recipe for those whose bad at cooking ")
title.pack()

def appetizer():

    a1 = PhotoImage(file = "cereal.png")
    cereal1 = Label(thanksgiving, image = a1)
    cereal1.place(x=100, y = 100)
    cereal1.photo = a1
    cereal1.pack()
    with open("1 Appetizers.txt", "r") as food:
        a12 = food.read()
        a22 = Label(thanksgiving, font = ("impact", 10), text = a12)
        a22.pack()

button1 = Button(thanksgiving, font = ("impact", 10), fg = "white", bg = "black" , text = "Appetizer", command = appetizer)
button1.pack(anchor = "w")
def appetizer2():
    a2 = PhotoImage(file = "marshmello.png")
    cereal2 = Label(thanksgiving, image = a2)
    cereal2.place(x=100, y = 100)
    cereal2.photo = a2
    cereal2.pack()
    with open("2 Appetizers.txt", "r") as food2:
        a11 = food2.read()
        a21 = Label(thanksgiving, text = a11)
        a21.pack()

button2 = Button(thanksgiving, font = ("impact", 10), fg = "white", bg = "black" , text = "Appetizer2", command =appetizer2)
button2.pack(anchor = "w")
thanksgiving.mainloop()
```

Comment: Take a look [ttk.Notebook](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-notebook) and put the appetizers into individual tab.